# what does (/ value /) mean? value is an input argument for a subroutine

Tags: arrays, fortran, arguments, subroutine

I am reading a Fortran code, inside it I don't understand why we use (/value/) instead of value. Could you please explain what is the difference? I do not know what does (/ /) do.

```
CALL BOUNDARY_CONDITIONS_SET(BOUNDARY_CONDITIONS,(/DOF_INDEX/),(/CONDITION/), &
   & (/VALUE/))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the routine expects an array, not values, as parameters.

`(/ a, b, c /)` creates an array with 3 elements: `a`, `b`, and `c`.

`(/DOF_INDEX/)` creates an array of length 1, with its only element being the value of `DOF_INDEX`.

Comment: Equivalently, `[` and `]` can be used to specify literal arrays. This is a later change to Fortran syntax. I tend to use them instead of `(/` and `/)` since they just look cleaner.